# Issues with Symbols when running windbg on windows xp sp3

Tags: debuggers, windbg

I have been trying to debug a crash using windbg on windows xp sp3. I have been getting the below error while trying to debug. I googled around and found the Microsoft no longer offers symbols exe as downloads and we need to link the MS symbols server in windbg. I tried that route too, but still failed to get rid of this error.

ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for ntdll.dll - 
ntdll!DbgBreakPoint

Is there a way I can download the symbols for windows xp sp3 on to my local machine and then run the windbg.

Comment: while windbg may be used for reverse engineering, the problem described in this post is not about reverse engineering and therefore does not seem to be a good fit for this site.

Comment: Try to use my repository https://github.com/Biswa96/PDBDownloader.